# How to get every word in multiple sentences into text cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, split

My final objective is to make a word cloud to see which word should get more attention and be more catchy look to the eye. (Word could be replace by problem if I could share real data). How can I get every single word from my cells full of sentences (even multiple sentences)?

I have searched the internet for my answer; I know how to get to my final objective. But the first appropriate step is missing for my problem. Every link I have found, even non related to my final objective, always have single cell with one word. Or if there is a sentence in a cell, they don't manage a lot of data.

A lot of data for me is a thousand cell text with multiple sentences.

Simple example of data:

```
A1 : I am sentence one.
B1 : Hey! I'm sentence two!
C1 : Could I be third sentence?
```

I expect to get this output :

```
A1 : I
A2 : am
A3 : sentence
A4 : one
A5 : .
A6 : Hey!
...
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you on?

Comment: You could split the sentences into words with **Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Space** and transpose the data from columns into rows with **Copy > Paste Special > Transpose**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple options really but you could try:

In `D1` and drag down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE($A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(CONCATENATE($A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1)))),(ROW()-1)*LEN(CONCATENATE($A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1))+1,LEN(CONCATENATE($A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1))))
```

If you have `TEXTJOIN()` you can use that instead of `CONCATENATE()` like so:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$A$1:$C$1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$A$1:$C$1)))),(ROW()-1)*LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$A$1:$C$1))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,$A$1:$C$1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the formula, it does exactly what I need and seem to be the right solution to filter a lot of data even dynamically :)

Anyone looking at this question, this small java program does great cloud with the advance option. Mix it with data filter from Excel and you have a great result.

http://www.wordle.net/

Comment: Suggest replacing `CONCATENATE($A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1)` with `CONCATENATE($A$1," ",$B$1," ",$C$1)` or `$A$1&" "&$B$1&" "&$C$1`